# How do I understand this sentence which ends in an adverb

Tags: translation

Character gets wounded by a sword slash and replies with this line.

> びっくりした。今の感じでもっと強くね

Does 強く describe 感じ here?

Is he saying he's more sensitive right now? If not, what is it describing? Do you normally end sentences with an adverb?

Comment: Please add context for this as it will help answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person who got wounded is a teacher, right?

- 今の感じ refers to the "feeling" of the slash he just saw and took.
- You can end a sentence with an adverb, or you can even make an adverb-only sentence, if the corresponding verb is easily inferred from the context. Here he is clearly trying to say もっと強くして or もっと強く斬って. (English speakers can say "Faster!" or "Stronger!", too, when the verb can be inferred.)
- 強く does not directly modify 感じ (see the translation below).

> 今の感じでもっと強くね
> Like this, but (make it) stronger, okay?